# Scala Seq.sliding() violating the docs rationale?

Tags: scala

When writing tests for some part of my system I found some weird behavior, which upon closer inspection boils down to the following:

```
scala> List(0, 1, 2, 3).sliding(2).toList
res36: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1), List(1, 2), List(2, 3))

scala> List(0, 1, 2).sliding(2).toList
res37: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1), List(1, 2))

scala> List(0, 1).sliding(2).toList
res38: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1))

scala> List(0).sliding(2).toList //I mean the result of this line
res39: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0))
```

To me it seems like `List.sliding()`, and the `sliding()` implementations for a number of other types are violating the guarantees given in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
def sliding(size: Int): Iterator[List[A]]
```

> Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window"
>   over them (as opposed to partitioning them, as is done in grouped.)
>
> **size:** the number of elements per group
>
> **returns:** An iterator producing lists of size size, **except the last and the only element will be truncated if there are fewer
>   elements than size**.

From what I understand there is a guarantee that all the lists that can be iterated over using the iterator returned by `sliding(2)` will be of length `2`. I find it hard to believe that this is a bug that got all the way to the current version of scala, so perhaps there's an explanation for this or I'm misunderstanding the docs?

I'm using "Scala version 2.10.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's is no such guarantee, and your pretty much emphasized the doc line that *explicitly* says so. Here it is again, with a different emphasis:

> returns: An iterator producing lists of size `size`, **except** the **last and
>   the only** element will be truncated **if there are fewer elements than
>   `size`**.

**So if you have a list that has length `n`, and call `.sliding(m)`, where `m > n`, *the last and the only element* of the result with have length `n`**.

In the case of:

```
List(0).sliding(2)
```

there is only one element (`n = 1`), you call `sliding(2)`, i.e. `m = 2, 2 > 1`, this causes the *last and only* element of the result to be truncated to `1`.

Comment: I don't believe that's entirely true: "So if you have a list that has length n, and call .sliding(m), the last element of the result with have length n % m" - you can see that is not what happens for any odd n>2 and m==2

Comment: @nietaki : sorry, brainfart there. Now it's correct. Technically I didn't have to remove the modulus now, but I believe it's clearer this way ;).

Comment: It might be just me, but when I put the emphasis on different parts of the docs, my original interpretation seems just as logical. I'm not a native speaker though, could be just me.

Comment: @nietaki : it's not just you, I also (evidently) find the wording inherently confusing. Perhaps a pull request to the [relevant scaladoc](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L191) would be in order?